# Gulp stuck on 'Starting'

Tags: javascript, gulp, shopify

I am using Gulp 4 to handle SCSS, JS, and image optimizations, compiling, minifying etc. for my Shopify theme, but I am having a problem with the gulp file actually running. I did read some similar questions and they mentioned to add a `return` which I have done, but with no luck. I would appreciate any insight on how to fix this and if there are any improvements I can make.

gulp.js:

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import plumber from "gulp-plumber";
import rename from "gulp-rename";
import sass from "gulp-sass";
import autoPrefixer from "gulp-autoprefixer";
import cssComb from "gulp-csscomb";
import cmq from "gulp-merge-media-queries";
import cleanCss from "gulp-clean-css";
import uglify from "gulp-uglify";
import concat from "gulp-concat";
import imageMin from "gulp-imagemin";
import cache from "gulp-cache";

gulp.task("images", function () {
  return gulp
    .src(["assets/images/**/*"])
    .pipe(
      plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          this.emit("end");
        },
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      cache(
        imageMin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })
      )
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets"));
});

gulp.task("styles", function () {
  return gulp
    .src(["assets/styles/**/*.scss"])
    .pipe(
      plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          this.emit("end");
        },
      })
    )
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoPrefixer())
    .pipe(cssComb())
    .pipe(cmq({ log: true }))
    .pipe(concat("theme.min.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/"))
    .pipe(
      rename({
        suffix: ".min",
      })
    )
    .pipe(cleanCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/"));
});

gulp.task("scripts", function () {
  return gulp
    .src(["assets/scripts/**/*.js"])
    .pipe(
      plumber({
        handleError: function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          this.emit("end");
        },
      })
    )
    .pipe(concat("theme.min.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/"))
    .pipe(
      rename({
        suffix: ".min",
      })
    )
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("assets/"));
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
  gulp.watch("app/css/*.css", gulp.series("styles"));
  gulp.watch("app/js/*.js", gulp.series("scripts"));
  gulp.watch("app/img/*", gulp.series("images"));
});
```

Currently when running `gulp watch` it's only outputting `Starting 'watch'...` similar to some previously asked questions, but I've already implemented the solution to most of those questions, but no luck still.

Comment: And when you modify and save one of your watched files, do those tasks run?

Comment: No, unfortunately not